# Linkedin API - Adding Ad Account Pragmatically to MDP

Tags: linkedin-api

I am having trouble finding API call (at this stage I am not sure if it exists) to add ad account to my "Marketing Developer Platform Settings" in the LinkedIn APP

[image]

The only way I found is adding it manually as per the image above, did anyone found an another solution on how to do it programmatically?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/marketing-tiers

At the very bottom of this page, it say's 

"Only accounts that have been configured for access in the Ad Accounts tab of your application can be managed through the API.

You cannot create new accounts through the API in the Development Tier."

Does that mean once I get upgraded to basic tier I will get access to API to do such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

Linkedin require you to develop an app and then you will be granted the privilege of adding accounts with api.